# Is it possible to dynamically import modules?

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have many imports for angular components, and it looks like I can write a function to simplify the import. I just don't know how, but this should be simple.

Sample imports:

```
import {DashboardComponent} from './app/components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
angular.module('app.components').component('dashboard', DashboardComponent);

import {HeaderComponent} from './app/components/header/header.component';
angular.module('app.components').component('header', HeaderComponent);
```

The function below demonstrates what I want to achieve, however I'm missing two concepts to make it work:

1. How do I put a variable (`name`) in the `{}`?
2. Can I use an Angular filter in a function like `| ucfirst` in a JS file?

```
componentImporter('header');

function componentImporter(name)
{
    import {name | ucfirst + 'Component'} from './app/components/'+ name + '/' + name +'.component';

    angular.module('app.components').component(name, name | ucfirst + 'Component');
}
```

Finally an error I run into is:

> 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

So can this actually ever work?

Comment: See answer below, also what are you using for you're ES6 - ES5 compiler? Babel? Traceur?

Comment: Babel is my complier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So can this actually ever work?

**Short Answer:** No

**Long Answer**

The error you saw pretty much says it all... `import`s can't be nested inside conditionals, loops, or other expressions. Here's a [great article](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) on ES6 Modules that goes in depth on the subject. Another interesting note, also mentioned in that article, is that *imports are hoisted*, similar to functions.

> How to put a name in the {} and 2) can I use an angular filter in the fuction like | ucfirst in a js file?

From the article:

> ...the structure of ES6 modules is static

Using a variable in the `import` would make it dynamic. The bracket syntax you're using can only be written to do a partial `import`  (i.e. Importing named exports from the given module). This is really neat if you're using [tree shaking](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html?m=1), another article by Dr. Rauschmayer.

Personally I like keeping all my imports at the top of each file making it very easy to see what that particular module is dependent on.

#### Update

There is now the [dynamic `import()`](http://2ality.com/2017/01/import-operator.html) method. Some bundlers like webpack [already support](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-) this method natively. This method is what should be used for dynamic importing of modules. Note that "Dynamic Imports" is an umbrella topic that contains a few subtopics including "Code Splitting", "Dynamic Module Expressions", as well as using logic to determine whether a module and its dependencies should be loaded.

Comment: Thanks! I did find that import can't be nested on stackoverflow, but your link better explains the situation than the other answers I found.

Comment: @craig no problem... Yea I figure there's probably a few other questions that address dynamic imports. I wondered the same thing when I first started playing around with modules.

Comment: I would like to know if it is possible to have compile type checking in TypeScript with dynamic import. Something like DLL where in C/C++ one has compile type checking while dynamically loading implementation.

Comment: @vlakov I’m not too familiar with TypeScript but you should still be able to use the `import()` method. To set up TypeScript with webpack you can start [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript).

Comment: I use angular-cli that is using webpack. Then TypeScript makes it possible dynamic / lazy module loading: https://typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html